# Arin Bulk whois data perl Can't locate BulkWhois/Schema.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, perl

I have tried this on two operating systems (first on Fedora then on Ubuntu(recommended)) and I am still confused so I am reaching out to the community.

I have access to ARIN's bulk whois data and want to parse the xml file and throw it into a database.  I came across a Perl script that does exactly this in a github repo https://github.com/giovino/Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL.  This is done on Ubuntu and stored in a mysql database.

I followed all of the steps, 1.) Download the project, 2.) Untar, 3.) Install libraries, 4.) Install perl modules, 5.) Install mysql, start the mysql-server, and create the "BulkWhois" database as suggested.

When I run the command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/bulkwhois2database.pl --file ~/arin_db.xml --dbms mysql --database BulkWhois --host localhost --port 3306
```

I get this error message:

```
Can't locate BulkWhois/Schema.pm in @INC (you may need to install the BulkWhois::Schema module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/bulkwhois2database.pl line 12.BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/bulkwhois2database.pl line 12.
```

Line 12 in bulkwhois2database.pl:

```
use BulkWhois::Schema;
```

The error says `Can't locate BulkWhois/Schema.pm in @INC`. I know that in the directory above the one that `bulkwhois2database.pl` is in there is `Schema.pm`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/BulkWhois$ ls
Schema  Schema.pm
```

Do I need to move that somewhere?  Maybe there is another issue?

Comment: How did you do 3) Install libraries exactly? What the error message tells you is that this module is not installed in a path where perl searches for modules. So it is an installation problem.

Comment: I ran this and dont recall seeing an error :sudo cpan -f SQL::Translator DBIx::Class DBIx::Class::Schema XML::LibXML::Reader XML::Simple XML::LibXML::SAX XML::SAX XML::SAX::ParserFactory Log::Log4perl JSON @PatrickMevzek

Comment: The problem is regarding the installation of the `BulkWhois` Perl distribution. How did you install this one?

Comment: I don't think I did.  I'm not sure how to.  @PatrickMevzek

Comment: Besides installing it correctly, if you run your script like that it should find it: `cd ~/McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/ ; perl -I. bulkwhois2database.pl`; the `-I.` adds the current directory and hence will make perl find the module

Comment: Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at InsertManager/XMLSimpleInsertManager.pm line 22.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at InsertManager/XMLSimpleInsertManager.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at bulkwhois2database.pl line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bulkwhois2database.pl line 13.

Comment: That seemed to work then it moved down and failed at line 13. @PatrickMevzek

Comment: `sudo cpan -f Switch`

Comment: Awesome I think this is going to work.  It is saying I need to add the username and password for the MySQL database.  Let me add those to the end and run it again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! This worked and I see the tables in my "BulkWhois" database!  mp$ cd
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/ ; perl -I. bulkwhois2database.pl --file /tmp/arin_db.xml --dbms mysql --database BulkWhois --host localhost --port 3306 --user root @PatrickMevzek

Comment: This would be a good time to install https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::PrereqScanner::NotQuiteLite, run it against the repository, use it to write a cpanfile listing all the dependencies and then create a pull request to add that to this tool, including a manual on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all of the help from Patrick, we solved the issue I was having.

Add the -I adds the current directory and made perl find the missing perl module.

Needed to install the missing Switch module:

```
sudo cpan -f Switch
```

Final command that worked:

```
cd ~/McKizzle-Arin-XML-Data-to-MySQL-dc77a54/src/ ; perl -I. bulkwhois2database.pl --file /tmp/arin_db.xml --dbms mysql --database BulkWhois --host localhost --port 3306 --user root
```